# Classification with L8 Raw scenes VS L8 Surface Reflectance using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, landsat-8, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have created a classification using Google Earth Engine following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification) using [ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-algorithms-landsat-simplecomposite).
I know the algorithm only uses raw scenes (as the documentation says), but is there any reason to try to create a composite from the Surface Reflectance data?

If I create a code for the composite from L8 SR, will it have a positive effect on the output classification or is it a wasted effort?

I asked the question because almost everyone uses Landsat.simpleComposite, but my friend insists that the L8 Surface Reflectance is better.

```
// buffer (m)
function bufferPoints(radius, bounds) {
  return function(pt) {
    pt = ee.Feature(pt);
    return bounds ? pt.buffer(radius).bounds() : pt.buffer(radius);
  }
}

var land = ee.FeatureCollection("users/petrjanos/hlavni/mongolsko_2021");
var pts = ee.FeatureCollection("users/petrjanos/klasifikace/class")
            .map(bufferPoints(30, false))

// Make a cloud-free Landsat 8 TOA composite (from raw imagery).
var L8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1').filterBounds(pts)
var image = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: L8.filterDate('2020-06-01', '2020-09-30'),
  asFloat: true
});

// Use these bands for prediction.
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11'];


// This property stores the land cover labels as consecutive
// integers starting from zero.
var label = 'class';

// Overlay the points on the imagery to get training.
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: pts,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 30
});

// Train a CART classifier with default parameters.
var trained = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(training, label, bands);

// Classify the image with the same bands used for training.
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(trained);

// Display the inputs and the results.
Map.centerObject(geo, 8);
Map//.addLayer(image.clip(land), {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.4}, 'image');
Map.addLayer(classified.clip(land),
             {min: 0, max: 3, palette: ['blue', 'red', 'purple', 'green']},
             'classification');
```

link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/68ad9918a02b15e4a7113ad05fc2340d

Comment: See ["Classification and Change Detection Using Landsat TM Data: When and How to Correct Atmospheric Effects?"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0034425700001693). If you plan on publishing your work, I recommend at least using TOA so the values are a meaningful measure. [Venter and Sydenham (2021)](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/13/12/2301/htm) found the TOA did not greatly improve classification over SR (for Sentinel-2). Landsat SR has the advantage of the CFmask cloud/shadow mask ([example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c8a6c0e05a9305ee8dce3f3a329161d7)).

Comment: Thanks, I understand this, but it strikes me that all the examples on the internet for classification in GEE use raw images (and calculate TAO). I guess if this was not the correct way, they wouldn't use this data and wouldn't mention it in Google's tutorials... maybe as you reference the "Venter and Sydenham (2021)" article, there is not that much difference in TAO and SR. Maybe that's why GEE is working with the raw scemes and TAO..